# I need a signal when my furnace fan turns on

Tags: hvac, furnace

I want to install a motorized fresh air damper that opens when my furnace fan comes on. Is there a place where I can pull this signal off of the furnace board? Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the make and model of your furnace, as well as a copy of its wiring diagram?

Comment: On most systems the "G" wire (not necessarily green but connected to the G terminal) is the fan signal.  If it's active, specifically at +24V, the fan will be on.  If it's at 0V (or near that) the fan will be off.

Comment: If your furnace is old school you may need to put a pressure switch in the duct at the air handler, a simple pressure switch is easier than adding a vane switch, I have done this many times. Is your damper motor open spring return?

Comment: Tap into the feed from the fan.

Comment: @jwh20 gas or oil furnaces control their fans autonomously, with the G signal as an override-on

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. We'll need more info before we can help you. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: @EdBeal Any links with explanations about pressure switch? What is the meaning of "old school"?

Comment: @zzz777 any standard light duty pressure switch (ever hear the duct work pop when the fan turns on or off this only takes a little pressure) measured in  inches of water when an inch of water pressure the switch makes providing a possible signal. Old school the way we did it prior to modern high tech controllers with diaphrams and a leaf switch. On the duct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, depending on your furnace make/model, but assuming it's not too ancient, it likely has a signal wire coming from the furnace control board that can control a damper.

Alternatively, they do make "barometric" switches that can serve the same purpose. Installed in the return, such a switch would detect the lower pressure and activate a damper.

All that said though: opening a fresh air damper isn't necessarily going to introduce fresh air into your house, if there's not something pulling stale out out of the house. Assuming your fresh air damper feeds into the furnace return, then to the extent that the lower pressure in the return does pull in fresh air, that will reduce the draft at the return grill and cause the house air pressure to increase, pushing air out through chinks and cracks as best as can happen.

I suspect that in practice, you won't get much incoming fresh air from the damper. In any case, you might want to consider a more active approach, with a fan, or at least another exhaust damper that opens when the fresh air one does.

Bottom line: it's not really enough to just let fresh air in. You also need a solution to let the stale air out, to keep things balanced.

Comment: Thank you for the great advise! The furnace is a newer high efficiency model. I do have an interlock that turns on the fan when I run the range hood or a bathroom fan. I found out that I can use the Electronic Air Filter tap which gives 115vAC when the fan comes on and then just use a 24v transformer to connect to the Hoyme damper. Seems to work well. The house was built 10 years ago and they did not install a automatic air exchange system but there is a manual switch that will exchange the air. I could probably put a timer on that I suppose.